# Como linkar com outra pagina tendo a opção de escolher o valor no combobox?

Tags: php, javascript, asp

Minha página possui uma `div` que faz o `link` com uma outra página, essa outra página possui um `combobox`, em que cada `value` me traz uma tabela diferente do banco de dados.

JavaScript que faz o link com a página:

```
<script>
        function nova(){
            location.href="../Pagina/default.asp?vop=new";
        }
</script>
```

O código da `div`:

```
<div id="daily" align="center" class="botao red margem alignL"     onclick="nova();">
        Pagina_destino<br>Chart<br><img src="images/ic_pareto1.png">
</div>
```

E o código da `combobox`:

```
<select name="linha">
        <option value="ASM1" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM1" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 1</option>
        <option value="ASM2" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM2" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 2</option>
        <option value="ASM3" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM3" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 3</option>
        <option value="ASM4" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM4" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 4</option>
        <option value="ASM5" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM5" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 5</option>
        <option value="ASM6" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM6" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 6</option>
        <option value="ASM7" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM7" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 7</option>
        <option value="ASM8" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM8" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 8</option>
        <option value="ASM9" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM9" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 9</option>
        <option value="ASM10" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASM10" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly 10</option>
        <option value="ASMX" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASMX" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly X</option>
        <option value="ASMY" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASMY" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly Y</option>
        <option value="ASMZ" <%if request.form("linha") = "ASMZ" then response.write "selected"%>>Assembly Z</option>   
    </select>
```

Eu gostaria de não só linkar a página como também pelo href executar um `value` do `combobox`.

**Por exemplo:**

Pagina - `index.php`

Na pagina `index.php` tem uma `div`, ela chama um `href` no `javascript` que por sua vez me redireciona para outra pagina, a `default.asp`. Nessa `default.asp` tenho um `combobox` em que cada `value` tem uma informação diferente, por exemplo.

- value1 = a informação da linha 1
- value2 = a informação da linha2 e por ai vai

Como eu posso colocar ou trazer o `value` do `combobox` no `href=default.asp?vop=new` e mais o valor do `option`? Tem como fazer isso ou somente em `ajax` mesmo?

Eu não tenho muita familiaridade com `ajax`, alguém conhece uma maneira simples de fazer em `ajax`? O que eu preciso é acessar um valor de um `combobox` de outra pagina, e não apenas me redirecionar para outra pagina, mas que também possa acessar o `value` do `combobox`

Comment: A pergunta nao está muito clara, edite-a, coloque mais detalhes. Se entendi bem você vai ter de usar ajax.

Comment: Você tem uma div que faz o link? Porque não utiliza o link diretamente com a tag <a> ??